# Cannot resolve constructor while set Animation

Tags: animation, libgdx, sprite

Here is the code in the class,I am using libgdx to develop a game but i don't how to solve the error about
(Cannot resolve constructor 'Sprite(java.lang.Object)' )in the render.

```
public class GamePage implements Screen{

    private static final float FRAME_DURATION = 1.0f / 15.0f;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TextureAtlas boxAtlas;
    private Animation boxAnim;
    private float boxTime;
    private Sprite spritebox;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        boxAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ybanim.pack"));
        boxAnim = new Animation(FRAME_DURATION, boxAtlas.getRegions(), Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        boxTime += delta;
        spritebox = new Sprite(boxanim.getKeyFrame(boxTime, true));
        spritebox.setPosition(0,0);

        batch.begin();
        spritebox.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`boxanim.getKeyFrame(boxTime, true)` returning `Object` and no constructor available in `Sprite` class that can take `Object` as parameter.

---

From gdx version 1.9.5 `Animation` class is now generic, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/4448) for the same. so declare your animation in this way :

```
Animation<TextureRegion> boxAnim;
```